# Abnormal behaviour of java.util.List based on number of elements in it

Tags: java, list, collections, iterator, concurrentmodification

I know that if the Collection will be changed while some thread is traversing over it using iterator, the iterator.next() will throw a [ConcurrentModificationException](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ConcurrentModificationException.html).

But it shows different behavior depending on the number of elements in the list.

I tried a code snippet in which I traversed a list in for-each loop and in between it's traversal removed an element from the list using remove() method of the list.

Ideally it should throw a ConcurrentModificationException in this condition without depending on number of elements in the list, But it is not true when number of elements in list are two.

**Case 1:**  Number of elements in list - 1

```
 public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        List<String> list=new ArrayList<String>();
        list.add("One");

        for (String string : list) 
        {
            System.out.println(string);
            list.remove(string);
        }
    }
```

> **Output**: One
>
> Exception in thread "main" java.util.ConcurrentModificationException

That's was as expected.

**Case 2:** Number of elements in list - 2

```
 public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        List<String> list=new ArrayList<String>();
        list.add("One");
        list.add("two");

        for (String string : list) 
        {
            System.out.println(string);
            list.remove(string);
        }
    }
```

> Output:   One

**No Exception is thrown?????????**

**Case 3:** Number of elements in list - 3

```
 public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        List<String> list=new ArrayList<String>();
        list.add("One");
        list.add("Two");
        list.add("Three");

        for (String string : list) 
        {
            System.out.println(string);
            list.remove(string);
        }
    }
```

> **Output**: One
>
> Exception in thread "main" java.util.ConcurrentModificationException

Again an exception is thrown which is ideal behavior.

*But why it runs properly in **case-2** without throwing any ConcurrentModificationException.*

Comment: *Is this some kind of bug in java*. Really? You're asking if there's a bug in a Java class created over a decade ago that is used by millions of people?

Comment: @BrianRoach: I am just asking why java is showing different behavior based on size of list. I don't know it is a bug or not.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/index.html?java/util/ArrayList.html) (emphasis mine):

> The iterators returned by this class's `iterator` and `listIterator`
>   methods are *fail-fast*: if the list is structurally modified at any
>   time after the iterator is created, in any way except through the
>   iterator's own `remove` or `add` methods, the iterator will throw a
>   `ConcurrentModificationException`. Thus, in the face of concurrent
>   modification, the iterator fails quickly and cleanly, rather than
>   risking arbitrary, non-deterministic behavior at an undetermined time
>   in the future.
>
> Note that the fail-fast behavior of an iterator cannot be guaranteed
>   as it is, generally speaking, impossible to make any hard guarantees
>   in the presence of unsynchronized concurrent modification. **Fail-fast
>   iterators throw `ConcurrentModificationException` on a best-effort
>   basis.** Therefore, it would be wrong to write a program that depended
>   on this exception for its correctness: *the fail-fast behavior of
>   iterators should be used only to detect bugs*.

Answer (score 7):

The previous answers posted show you the relevant docs that explain why this is appropriate behavior; you are not *guaranteed* to receive that exception.

If you're really interested in seeing *why* you don't receive it with only two elements (or really, if you remove the next to last element regardless of the size), you can look at the [source code for `ArrayList`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/ArrayList.java).

Your loop:

```
for (String string : list)
```

is actually:

```
for(Iterator<String> i = list.iterator(); i.hasNext(); ) {
    String string = i.next();
    ...
}
```

Internally in Arraylist there is an `int size` that represents the current number of elements in the `ArrayList`. It is decremented when you call `remove()`.

Inside the `Iterator` there is an `int cursor` that represents the current location (index) of the `Iterator`. It gets incremented when you call `next()`

`hasNext()` in the `Iterator` checks the current cursor position against the size.

In your example the chain of events is as follows:

- `cursor` starts at `0`, `size` starts at `2`
- `next()` is called, `cursor` incremented to `1`.
- `remove()` is called, `size` is decremented to `1`
- `hasNext()` compares `cursor` to `size`, finds they are the same, returns `false`
- loop exits without throwing exception

So if you remove the next to last element in any size `ArrayList` while iterating through it you will not receive an exception. (Also worth noting is that you will never process the last element in that list in the loop; your example only prints `One` for that reason).

Remember though - this is an *implementation detail* and is not guaranteed. The docs tell you that you should not rely on the exception being thrown (or not thrown). `ArrayList` could be rewritten in a different way where the above no longer applies and the exception *is* thrown (and in fact, in another JVM that may well already be the case).

Answer (score 0):

It seems when you remove the specified element from the list,the list does not know its size have been changed.

Try this:

[Iterator.remove()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html#remove%28%29)

> Removes from the underlying collection the last element returned by
>   the iterator (optional operation). This method can be called only once
>   per call to next. The behavior of an iterator is unspecified if the
>   underlying collection is modified while the iteration is in progress
>   in any way other than by calling this method.

Comment: I know the reason of the exception and how to resolve it, But i am asking about the reason why it is not coming in case-2.